# Channel creation using node fabric sdk 2.2

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Hey is there any way to create a channel in fabric-network using fabric-network npm package.
I found this "https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Gateway.html#getClient__anchor" but this is for fabric-sdk-nod 1.4 and i am working on 2.2.

didn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The Fabric programming model introduced with Fabric v1.4 (fabric-network, fabric-gateway-java etc.) focus on supporting business applications to submit and evaluate (query) transactions, and to receive events. Using the Fabric CLI commands became the primary supported tool for admin operations. This approach continues with the new Fabric Gateway client API, which is the primary supported client API for Fabric v2.4 onwards, replacing the legacy SDKs:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway

Programmatic admin capability is something that does regularly get requested by the community and, at the time of writing, there is an effort underway to develop a new Fabric admin API separate from the client application APIs/SDKs:

https://github.com/Hyperledger-TWGC/fabric-admin-sdk

I believe the Node implementation is well advanced and usable.

Again, at the time of writing, there is an open proposal to move this to a first-class Hyperledger project:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-rfcs/pull/55